# Page orientation option doesn't work with new class

Tags: document-classes, class-options

This is the new class I have created preloading `article` class

```
\LoadClassWithOptions{article}
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{chain}[4/4/2022]
%Packages
\RequirePackage{tabularx}
\RequirePackage{array}
```

and the `.tex` file is

```
\documentclass[a4paper,landscape]{chain}
```

Result
[image: screenshot]

The page doesn't render in landscape, although the content of the page moves to the center of the page and gets cut off. I have looked through the class guide and didn't understand how to solve this problem.

Comment: load e.g. the graphics package.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer adding graphics package with requirepackage solved the problem. Isn't it included in the article class already?

Comment: the article class is too old and doesn't set the "media box" (the pdf background), so you need another package that does it (geometry or hyperref would do it too).  (This will perhaps change in future, but it could change existing documents, so it is not decided yet.)